# services using alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

This is my code, but it does not work.

In settings activtiy:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnBootReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000, 
                 pendingIntent);
```

In BroadcastReceiver:

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CharSequence from = "xyz";
CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Settings.class), 0);
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,  "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
mgr.notify(1, notif);
```

Comment: did you find a sollution in that?

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to start your intent in 1 second using the `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` unit, 
you might want to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`

Differences are explained here : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html
`AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` must be used with `currentTimeMillis()`;

Otherwise you can use the flag : 
`AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` to provide a time calculated with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`

Flags are explained here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html.